# Rails 5 LoadError (cannot load such file -- roo)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5, roo

I cannot seem to load roo and want to use it to import google spreadsheets

Im using rails 5.2.3, ruby 2.6.1p33

roo (2.8.2, 2.7.1)

Does anyone have an idea why this is happening?

When I try requiring roo in irb console, it seems to be working

```rb
class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_secure_password

  validates :username, presence: true, uniqueness: true

  require 'roo'

  def self.import(file)
    spreadsheet = Roo::Spreadsheet.open(file.path)
  end
end
```

Gemfile

```
gem "roo", "~> 2.8.0"
```

Comment: What does your `gem roo` directive look like in your `Gemfile`? Have you tried putting `require 'roo'` in `config/application.rb`?

Comment: I'm not sure if this fixed it or the server restart lol 
But thank you so much!!! It's working now!

Comment: Great! Besides restarting the server, what did you do? Anything?

Answer (score 0):

It's mostly an issue with your spring loader, run

```
  bundle exec spring stop
  bundle exec spring start
```